# Upsert records in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert-update, upsert

I am working with postgresql database and I have below update query which works fine -

```
    'UPDATE "main"."item_vendor"\n' +
    '    SET\n' +
    '      "vendor_id" = $1, "audit_by" = $2\n' +
    '    \n' +
    '  FROM "main"."item"\n' +
    '\n' +
    '    \n' +
    '  WHERE \n' +
    '  "main"."item"."id" IN ($3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17)\n' +
    ' AND "main"."item".id = "main"."item_vendor".item_id\n',
  values: [
    '28',        17355915,
    '188646',    '188647',
    '188648',    '188649',
    '188650',    '188749',
    '188750',    '188751',
    '188752',    '188753',
    '200000691', '200000693',
    '200000695', '200000697',
    '200000699'
  ]
```

Now I need to convert above query so that it can insert as well if records doesn't exist. What is the right way to change my above query to upsert query (update if row exists and if it doesn't then just insert it)? I am using postgresql 14 version.

Confusion I have is - How do I convert above query into below which does the upsert after reading the documentation.

```
INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... ON CONFLICT (key) DO UPDATE
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that most languages have a way to make a big string like that in one block, `'\n'` is often literally `\n`. What language are you using? Looks like Ruby, try a [here doc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Ruby).

Comment: These queries are generated by typescript for me so as of now I am trying to figure out the query that I need for upsert so that I can use that.

Comment: What is/are the key(s) to detect a conflict? Are vendor_id and audit_by the only columns you need to insert into item_vendor?

Comment: Update will be like normal update which is what I have in my above question. And yes vendor_id and audit_by are the only columns I need to insert into item_vendor. If record exists then just update it and if it doesn't exist then insert it.

Comment: How do you know if a record exists? You have to match on a column, usually the primary key. Is it item_vendor.item_id?

Comment: yes `item_vendor.item_id` it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Extract the select. It needs to be converted to a join with the updated table. It's a left join so we get all the records from item, even if they're not in item_vendor.

```
select item.vendor_id, item.audit_by, item.id
from item
left join item_vendor on item.id = item_vendor.item_id
where item.id IN ($3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17)
```

2. Turn it into an insert...select.

```
insert into item_vendor(vendor_id, audit_by, item_id)
select item.vendor_id, item.audit_by, item.id
from item
left join item_vendor on item.id = item_vendor.item_id
where item.id IN ($3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17)
```

3. Then add the `on conflict` clause. In order to tell if a record exists, you need to key on something unique in item_vendor. Usually this is the primary key. I'm just going to guess what that is. The values of the rejected insert are all in the pseudo table `excluded`.

```
insert into item_vendor(vendor_id, audit_by, item_id)
select item.vendor_id, item.audit_by, item.id
from item
left join item_vendor on item.id = item_vendor.item_id
where item.id IN ($3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17)
on conflict(vendor_id) do
    update set vendor_id = excluded.vendor_id, audit_by = excluded.audit_by
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/5akCDO50)

Comment: Is left join needed here? Just curious

Comment: @rosed Yes, for the reason stated. If you use a normal join, items which are not in item_vendor will never be selected and never inserted defeating the point of the upsert.

Comment: I am getting this error when I am running the query. Any idea why I am getting this? `null value in column \"item_id\" of relation \"item_vendor\" violates not-null constraint`

Comment: @rosed You did not give us a schema to work with, so I had to make some guesses. You'll have to modify the details to fit your schema.

Comment: Got it now. I have updated the question to provide schema details as well. Let me know if I need to change anything in the query. @Schwern

Comment: @rosed When inserting into item_vendor, you need to fill in all the not null fields. You might want to add defaults. It also looks like you're missing foreign keys. Finally, those triggers could be interfering. As to your error, I don't know without context. `item_id` is coming from `item.id` which cannot be null.